# How to I make a circle constantly follow the mouse pointer forever using event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to make an Agar.io clone and everything was going well until I got to the mouse movement. I added the mouse move event to the document and the circle only moves toward the mouse when the mouse is moving, and I want it to move when the mouse is moving and stopping. I've tried to use on mouse move but it seems to do nothing. In Processing JavaScript you can access the mouse coordinates whenever you want, but in JavaScript, you can't do that and I was wondering how to make a circle constantly follow the mouse pointer.

Here is some of my code for the mouse:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", m);

function m(e) {
    let mouseX=e.clientX;
    let mouseY=e.clientY

    mouseX-=player.pos.x;
    mouseY-=player.pos.y;

    let mouse=Math.atan2(mouseX, mouseY);

    player.pos.x+=Math.sin(mouse)/0.3;
    player.pos.y+=Math.cos(mouse)/0.3;

    if (player.pos.x > 0 && player.pos.x < 900) {
        ctx.translate(-Math.sin(mouse)/0.3, 0);
    } 

    if (player.pos.y > 0 && player.pos.y < 900) {
        ctx.translate(0, -Math.cos(mouse)/0.3)
    }
}
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/doss2ecd/1/

Comment: When a cursor is stopped, the last coordinates still apply. So all you need to do in that case is store the mouseX/mouseY in a higher scope.
The calculations for the movement of the rest of the game could/should be added to the "gameloop" instead of the events themselves.

Comment: Just a comment, if you want to get to a similar behavior as in the Agar.io game notice in the game the circle is actually never moving. it's the all 'world' around it that move while circle is always stays in the center of the screen. if the circle was actually moving and the 'world' was static the circle would get very fast out of the screen boundaries...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a better way to do this might be on mousemove update your global mouse coordinates. Then inside your update/draw event move the player and position the camera

Comment: So I did this and now player.pos.x and y are equal to NaN and I don't know why All I'm doing is finding the atan2 of mouseX and mouseY.

This is in the draw function:
mouseX-=player.pos.x;
 mouseY-=player.pos.y;
 
 player.pos.x+=Math.sin(mouse)/0.3;
 player.pos.y+=Math.cos(mouse)/0.3;
 
 if (player.pos.x > 0 && player.pos.x < 900) {
  ctx.translate(-Math.sin(mouse)/0.3, 0);
 } 
 
 if (player.pos.y > 0 && player.pos.y < 900) {
  ctx.translate(0, -Math.cos(mouse)/0.3)
 }

This is in the mouse function:
 mouseX=e.clientX;
 mouseY=e.clientY;
 mouse=Math.atan2(mouseX, mouseY);

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a vector from the center of your canvas to the mouse pointer and then move along that vector till you hit the boundaries of your game field. The position should be updated with your gameloop or setTimeout()
e.g.

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
    var mousePos = convertPosInRelationToCanvasSize(e.clientX,e.clientY)
    moveVector = {X:mousePos.x-canvas.HalfWidth,Y:mousePos.y-canvas.HalfHeight}
    normalizeVector(moveVector); // adjusts values to -1.0-1.0
}

function moveCircle() {
   circle.X += moveVector.X*speed;
   circle.Y += moveVector.Y*speed;
}

setTimeout(moveCircle,20); // update circle position every 20ms
```

Canvas size: 100x100 (center 50:50)
Mouse position 80:20 (right up)

moveVector={X:30,Y:-30} //and then normalized

so your circle would move right up